# call apex method from Form element

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, form

Is there a way to call Apex method to save the values in a form element?
For example :

```
<form id="scan-form" action="https://www.huika.com/payment/index.php/starting" method="post"
          target="_blank" charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onclick="actionFunctionMethod();">


        <input id="zehut" name="zehut" value="1212112" />
        <input id="name" name="name" value="bingo" />
        <input id="email" name="email" value="bingo0@gmail.com" />
        <input id="token" name="token" value="233243455354dfggdf4" />
        <input id="sum" name="sum" value="100" />

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
```

I tried to use actionFunction - But it has to use inside apex:form..

The reason for not using the apex:form element, is that I can't make a redirection following the Post method for sending the data.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you return a PageReference from the actionFunction method instead? Don't do any rerenders and and your redirection will happen!

Comment: @Saket Joshi actionFunction means I would need to replace the form element with apex:form element.
I need to make a Post redirection with params from the form - But when using the :
 
`pageRef.getParameters().put('id','121212')`
 for example inside the pageRefenrence function - Its pass on the URL as get and not as Post - and this is a problem. Any suggestion? Or Enlightenment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling any network operation during a form post is destined to fail, as the browser severs all connections as part of its "unload" event. Instead, you would still want an apex:form, and you'd have a normal form for submitting afterwards. I won't write a full answer, but it would start off like this:

```
<script>
  function submitForm() {
    document.querySelector("#secondForm").submit();
  }
</script>
<apex:form>
  <apex:input value="{!zehut}" label="Zehut" ... />
  ...
  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" rerender="hiddenForm" oncomplete="submitForm();" 
     label="Submit" />
</apex:form>
<apex:outputText id="hiddenForm">
  <form id="secondForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="zehut" value="{!zehut}" />
    ...
  </form>
</apex:outputText>
```

Other alternatives are possible as well, but the main thing is that you need to make sure the first action fully commits before submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @sfdcfox
 Its exactly what I needed!!
But I have one question on it if I may - 
how can I pass the values to the <input> tag in the form? 
for example :  `<input id="zehut" name="zehut" value="{!zehut}" />` because this is the form I need eventaully to be submitted.
Thanks!!

 By the way - is there a way of doing it from Serverside? with PageReference maybe? I didnt find a way to pass the values as a post. Just as a get on the URL..

Comment: @Salvation pagereference is rather limited, so no. The *specific* reason why I gave the code as above is because it should work. The order of operations is important here.